# Group nearby elements of a vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector and what I would like to do is "label" the elements into groups depending on how close they are.

Example data

```
c(34, 34, 35, 35, 120, 121, 121, 365, 366)
```

In this case I would like to group `34, 34, 35, 35` into one group, then `120, 121, 121` into another and finally `365, 366` into yet another group.

Is there some smart way to do so?

Comment: see `kmeans` algorithm.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel you should write an answer based on that comment.

Comment: `kmeans(data,3)` if `data`is your vector

Comment: Unfortunately @muc8, usually you do not know `k` in advance, this is not so simplistic like this ;)

Comment: You could also use the `cut()` function.  For example, `cut(data, c(0, 50, 200, 500)` if `data` is your vector.

Comment: The OP talks explicitly about creating 3 clusters here, so I am referring to this. Obviously, it is different working on larger data sets, but the OP provides no information about that.

Comment: Agree that OP should clarify this, but it's always good to consider the general case rather than making particular assumptions! @Jan V. Adams, your approach is biased by the data (and wrong) since you identified the group in cut `in fonction of` the order of magnitude in each group in data ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually one can use special R packages for clustering. But it could be a nice exercise in vector wrangling:

#### If you know the number of clusters (k)

... and your vector is (ordered) `vec`:

```
k <- 3
clusters <- diff(c(0, tail(order(diff(vec)), k-1), length(vec)))
```

To split vector by clusters use split:

```
split(vec, rep(1:length(clusters), clusters))
```

#### Or you only know the max distance

Define max difference `d`:

```
d <- 10
clusters <- diff(c(0, tail(order(diff(vec)), sum(diff(vec)>d)), length(vec)))
```

To split vector by clusters use split:

```
split(vec, rep(1:length(clusters), clusters))
```

Comment: Thank you, bergant. My problem is that I do not know the number of clusters a priori...

Comment: You have to provide some criteria. In the example there is also a variant with `d` = max distance inside a cluster. Could you estimate the max distance `d` from `sort( diff(vec))` ?

Comment: Yes, I know the max distance, which is always fixed for me

Comment: Then the plan B should be OK.